# Horizontal Continuous Slider

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, slider, touch

I am looking for a jquery horizontal slider that moves to the right and left by using arrows, touch events and mouse click. The slider must contain one single item, which is scrolled horizontally with the events I mentioned. Do you know any I can use with those characteristics?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this : http://bxslider.com/examples/carousel-demystified
It supports Mouse Click, Touch based movement directly. And you can capture Keypress events manually and use its API to move between slides. Like this:

```
slider = $('.bxslider').bxSlider();
document.addEventListener('keypress', function (e) {
    if (e.charCode === 39) {
        slider.goToNextSlide();
        e.preventDefault();
    } else if (e.charCode === 37) {
        slider.goToPrevSlide();
        e.preventDefault();
    }
});
```